# PayPal - Automatic Handling of Transactions

Tags: c#, transactions, paypal

Let us say that I have the following URL for PayPal

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_donations&business=blablabla@gmail.com&item_name=BlaBlaBla&currency_code=EUR&amount=200
```

If the user clicks on the URL, he will be redirected to a PayPal page where he must enter his username and password.  Afterwards, he will be asked to authorize the transaction to the blablabla@gmail.com merchant account.

Is there any way to make the above automated?  For instance, let us say that I have a server, and I send my PayPal username and password to the server, along with other information such as transaction number and merchant's account.  The server would then **automatically** process the transaction using PayPal.

Is there any API that can be used to do this?  Please don't go into ethical issues and the like.  I have my reasons for doing this.  I know that in reality people can just log-into their PayPal account and pay from there.

Comment: You could do something like `keepass` does. When you perform a paste action (ctrl+V) it finds a loginfield in your browser and types the username, presses tab, types the password, presses enter. Perhaps something like that will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you look at their API it is well worth?

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_dcc_hub-outside

and

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_api_masspay